# Как отменить действие при нажатии?

Tags: java, android

Есть таймер повторяющий одно и то-же действие через определенный интервал вмени.Таймер повторяется бесконечно раз .Но мне надо как то добавить кнопку отмены .Допустим запустил случайно но хочу остановить.
Вот код таймера

```
final TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        i++;
        System.out.println("Request  N +" +i);
        Sender s = new Sender(MainActivity.this,urlAddress,lat,lot);
        s.execute();
    }
};

final Timer timer =new Timer();
```

а вот и запуск таймера

```
saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask,0,3000);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask,0,8000);
            saveBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    
        }
    });
}
```

А как сделать отмену этого таймера?

Спасибо всем кто откликнется

Answer (score 5):

```
timer.cancel();
timer.purge();
```

Comment: а вот на днях плакал что ниче незнаешь :)

Comment: Просто погуглил :))))